convertir un string a un date en neo4j
Estoy pasando datos de un csv a neo4j, como todos se pasan como string debo convertir algunos por ejemplo como toInteger,etc. El problema son las fechas suponiendo que tengo '2024-05-02' no encuentro en la documentación ni en otro lados como pasarlo a Date, abajo muestro como los estoy pasando:

